# Extending a 1-element list with another valid list returning NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, extending

I have a list I generate like this:

```
cols = [td['data-stat'] for td in rows[0].find_all("td")]
```

`cols` contains:
`['age','team_id','lg_id','pos','g','gs','mp','fg', ...]`
as it should.  However, when I insert "season" to the beginning OR extend `["season"]` with `cols`, I suddenly get `NoneType`:

```
new_cols = ["season"].extend(cols)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method doesn't return a value, it alters an existing one.

If you want a separate list that contains every element in the `cols` list, along with the `"extend"` string, use the `list.copy()` method to duplicate the list, and use the `list.extend()` method on the new list:

```
new_cols = cols.copy() 
new_cols.extend(["season"])
```

If you do not intend to keep the old list, then you can directly use the `list.extend()` method on the old list:

```
cols.extend(["extend"])
```